# how to make one child component re-render another child component through a parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm able to successfully pass props from child to parent then to another parent. I'm struggling to make one child's button re-render another child. The two children components are connected  by a parent component called `App.js`
Here's a sketch of the process:

```
1) <ConceptTabs.js/> contains a button that is clicked 
2) this button sends an integer that bubbles up to its parent, App.js.
3) App.js sends this integer to its child < Header.js/>
4) <Header.js/> sends this integer to < Audio2.js/>
5) <Audio2.js /> re-renders once it receives this integer
```

In my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-states-ep03t?file=/src/App.js), I get the integer to bubble up all the way to `<Audio2.js/>`... but `<Audio2.js />`only rerenders when the button that lives inside of it gets pushed. RATHER, it should automatically re-render anytime a button from child, `<ConceptTabs.js/>` gets pushed.

The structure of the project looks like this:

```
src/
  App.js
  components/
     header.js
     Audio2.js
     ConceptTabs.js
```

Please see my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-states-ep03t?file=/src/App.js) as well (I've pasted it below too)

Audio2.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Pause, Play } from "react-feather";
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function AudioPlayer(props) {

  // variable to play audio in loop
  const [isPlay, isPlaying] = useState(0);
  const[currentPage] = useState(props.currPage)

  useEffect( ()=>{
    console.log('hello');
    setTimeout( ()=>{ console.log('hello2'); }, 2000);
 });

  const [currPage, updatePageAudio] = useState({
    currPage: props.currPage,
  });

  console.log("Audio!!", props.currPage)

  console.log("Audio2!!", currentPage)

  const handlePlaying = () => {
    if (isPlay) {
      isPlaying(0);
    } else {
      isPlaying(1);
    }
  };

  console.log("Audio", currPage);

  return (
        <button
          onClick={()=>handlePlaying()}
        >
          <>{isPlay ? "Pause: and it should restart back to original state when a new button on ConceptTabs.js is pushed" : "Listen to this page: This button should display the index of whichever button was pushed in ConceptTabs.js"}</>
        </button>
  );
}

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import Audio from "./Audio2"

function Header (props) {

  console.log("header", props.currPage)
  
  return (
    //  < Audio currPage={()=>props.handleChange2()}/>
    < Audio currPage={ props.currPage}/>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

App.js

```
import Header from "./components/header";
import ConceptTabs from "./components/ConceptTabs";

function App() {

  let pageID = 0
  // goes to ConceptTabs
  let handleChange = (id) => {
    console.log("clicked", id);
    handleChange2(id)
    pageID = id
    return id
  };

// Goes to Audio2
  let handleChange2 = (id) => {
    console.log("clicked2", id);
    return id
  };

  console.log("pageID", pageID)


  return (
    <>
      <Header currPage={pageID}  />
      <br />
        <ConceptTabs handleChangeProps={handleChange} />
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and finally ConceptTabs.js

```
import React from "react";

function Tabs (props) {

  return (
    <>
     <button onClick={()=>props.handleChangeProps(1)} > 
     ONE
    </button> 
    <br />
    <button onClick={()=>props.handleChangeProps(2)} > 
     TWO
    </button> 
    <br />
    <button onClick={()=>props.handleChangeProps(3)} > 
     THRE
    </button> 

    </>
  );
}

export default Tabs;
```

Comment: Your `pageID` variable at the top of your app is not being tracked by React - so React has no idea that it has been changed. If you wrap it in a `useState()` things should be better

Comment: Also in `AudioPlayer` you're taking the passed-in `currPage` prop, and using it as the initial value of a `useState()` - generally this is considered an [antipattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) as it's likely to cause updates to be lost - which is exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: expanding on what @millhouse has stated above, in `AudioPlayer` you might want to have a `useEffect(() => {  // set your local state here  },[props.currPage])` . Now, any change in `props.currPage` will get tracked and you can update your local state(s)